# Why doesn't my MenuListener Work?

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenubar

I am making a text editor and I am already snagged up on the Menu Listener
when i make this code,

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Editor extends CenteredFrame{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2549009292395922530L;
    public Editor(String title){
        super();
    }
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    //add a menu cut
    JMenu cut = new JMenu("Edit");
    cut.addMenuListener(this);
    }
```

there are errors.

```
They usually say
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration
    - Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete MethodHeaderName
    - Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after this token
    - Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete QualifiedName
```

Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: You're trying to write executable code outside of executable context (ie a method or constructor)

Comment: Move the code back into the constructor ... probably

Comment: And then it generatesThe method addMenuListener(MenuListener) in the type JMenu is not applicable for the arguments (Editor)

Comment: Okay, so I think you seriously need to have a look at [What Is an Interface?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html), [Writing Event Listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/) and probably [How to Use Menus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html)

Comment: Move those statements into the Constructor, go read the Swing API and try some tutorials. Then, continue.